# how to use a different model in streamlit

Tags: streamlit

I have made my streamlit, in my py file I put a code :

```
prediction = df_Annmodel.predict(input_reshape)
print(prediction)
```

as I wanted to use my ANN model, now I want to use my random forest model or logistic reg model, do I need to save them as h5 file again?
How can I use them in my streamlit?
Thank you

I tried this:

```
  prediction = df_Annmodel.predict(input_reshape)
  print(prediction)
```

it worked but I need a different model